# C++ Printing an integer derived from a string's character

Tags: c++, string, printing, integer

I'd like to print the very first number.  For some reason, its printing out as 49 instead of 1...

```
 int n = 111111251;
 string s = to_string(n);
 int num = s[0];
 cout << num << endl;
```

Comment: It's printing 49 because the numerical value of the char literal '1' is 49 in the encoding you use. Just cout `s[0]`

Comment: To find out which "encoding you use" run: `locale` in Linux or `chcp` in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Its printing out `49` because that is the [ascii value of `1`](http://www.asciitable.com/).

If you want to print out the character, just print out `s[0]` directly, or convert it back to an `int` properly.  Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 111111251;
    string s = to_string(n);
    cout << s[0] << endl;

    int num = s[0];
    cout << num << endl;

    int num2 = s[0] - '0';
    cout << num2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out:

```
1
49
1
```

Answer (score 0):

While doing the right thing converting an integer to a string you change the type of the first element in the string from 'char' to 'int'. That effects the output: The character representation is still '1', but the numerical value is (ASCII) 49 (Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

You probably want `char character = s[0]; cout << character << endl;` or `int num = s[0]; cout << char(num) << endl;`

Answer (score -1):

49 is the ASCII value of 1.

Hope I helped,

Comment: It would be more correct to say that 49 is the ASCII value of '1'. Hope I helped.:)